# Evidence for Aristotle being an empiricist?

Tags: aristotle, empiricism

Most secondary sources tell me yes, but can anyone provide me with primary evidence of this. A short quote would be sufficient, this is time sensitive (got an essay due tomorrow) so thank you in advance xx

Comment: Obviously, he was not an "empiricist" in the modern (XVII Centurt on) sense. But A's interest in empirical observations was paramount. See [Aristotle’s Biology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-biology/) and [Aristotle’s Psychology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-psychology/).

Comment: See e.g. J.Barnes, [Aristotle: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=I3HMSHAHHDcC&pg=PA92), **Ch.13 Empiricism**.

Comment: SEP [Aristotle’s Empiricism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/empiricism-ancient-medieval/#ArisEmpi) gives plenty of quotes with exact references, as well as explains what his "empiricism" means, "*no one can learn anything at all in the absence of sense*", "*to gain light on things imperceptible we must use the evidence of perceptible things*", "*we should accept what is evident to the senses rather than [mere] reasoning*", etc.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is that it is better to read what Aristotle wrote than to fit what he wrote into a conceptual box such as 'empiricism', 'idealism' and so on. All such boxes - such conceptualisations - turn out on scholarly inspection to be vague and imprecise anyway. This is not a criticism. At all. Just a bit of guidance.

Now for your question. If we are going to consider Aristotle's 'empiricism' here's a lead into the issue:

## Statement of methodology: Posterior Analytics II. 19

> A classic question that has divided scholarship on Aristotle from the Greek
> commentators forward is whether, when it comes to scientific first principles, Aristotle is an empiricist or a rationalist ...At first blush, it would seem obvious that Aristotle is on the empiricist/
> inductivist side of this issue. After all, the text that is often taken to state his
> definitive position on the question, Posterior Analytics II. 19, claims that there
> is a path that leads from perception to ‘the first universal in the soul’, and
> from there to first principles, a path described as ‘coming to know by induction’
> (APo. II. 19 100a3–b4). And it appears this path is characterized in very similar
> terms in the first chapter of the Metaphysics. More generally, as we will see, there
> appear to be explicit proclamations of empiricist commitments in his works in
> natural science. (James G. Lennox, 'Aristotle on Norms of Inquiry', HOPOS: The Journal of the International Society for the History of Philosophy of
> Science , Vol. 1, No. 1 (Spring 2011), pp. 23-46: 23-4.)

## Scientific practice

Aristotle advises the student of the natural world  - more precisely the world (unlike that studied by astronomy) of beings that come to be and pass away and are subject to conditional change - to study the phenomena first, and then the causes. See PA I.1.(639b7–10).

The History of Animals gives a wide range of examples of such study. When, for example, he discusses the cephalopods (*ta malakia*, the 'softies' or soft-bodied animals) he analyses and classifies on a basis that can only be provided empirically - by observation. Here he is, studying the phenomena:

> Among the animals called ‘soft-bodies’ these are the external parts: 1. the
> so-called feet; 2. the head, continuous with the feet; 3. the sac, containing
> the internal organs, which some mistakenly call the head; 4. the fin,
> which encircles the sac. In all of the soft-bodies the head turns out to be
> between the feet and the belly. Moreover, all have eight ‘feet’, and all have
> two rows of suckers, except for one kind of octopus.9 The cuttlefish, and
> the large and small calamary have a distinctive feature, two long tentacles,
> the ends of which are rough with two rows of suckers, by which they capture food and convey it to their mouth and fasten themselves to a rock
> when it storms, like an anchor. (523b21–33; cf. PA IV. 9 685a33–b2; Lennox: 34.)

On this basis one can theorise : identify natural kinds and the divisions between them.